# Code for Evidence Based Technical Analysis

Tags: books

I recently purchased [http://www.amazon.com/Evidence-Based-Technical-Analysis-Scientific-Statistical/dp/0470008741](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470008741)

Is there an open source repository that contains (or contains as close as possible):

- the code used
- the data used?

The main thing is that -- reading is great, but playing with data is even more fun.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not contact the author? His email address is on his [firm's website](http://www.hoodriverresearch.com/).

Comment: @user2936: You can accept one of the answers if you are satisfied by it :-)

Answer (score 3):

The companion website to the book [here](http://evidencebasedta.com/) has a PDF download ("Monte Carlo Permutation Evaluation of Trading Systems") on pages 18-20 of which there is C++ code for the permutation routine. Code for White's Reality Check test is available
from the [ttrTests](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ttrTests/) package for R.

Answer (score 2):

The Automated Trading System-blog has a few posts about the book with a helpful tool at the end:

- http://www.automated-trading-system.com/evidence-based-technical-analysis-aronson-book/
- http://www.automated-trading-system.com/bootstrap-test/

and here the conclusion with the free tool for the bootstrap-test:

- http://www.automated-trading-system.com/bootstrap-take-2-data-mining-bias-code-and-using-geometric-mean/